# Facebook application endless redirect

Tags: facebook

I started to program a little Facebook app. Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once './fb_sdk/facebook.php';

$config = array();

$config['appId'] = 'xxxx';
$config['secret'] = 'xxx';
$config['fileUpload'] = false;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$session = $facebook->getUser();

if ($session != 0) {
    try {
        $profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}

if ($profile) {
    echo "App okay!";
} else {
    $params = array(
      'scope' => 'user_about_me, publish_stream',
      'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxx/xxxx?sk=app_xxx'
    );

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

    echo "<script>top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>";  
}
?>
```

After allowing the app, I come to an endless redirect to the app page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is this code sitting? a canvas app? a page tab?

Comment: do you have a canvas URL set in the application settings? I know that property has an *undocumented* effect on some features including invites - i'm always suspicious of it :P

Comment: No, I didn't. I only set the tabpage settings and then I added the app to my site.

Comment: try setting the canvas URL - you can even have a simple JavaScript redirect as you did in your JavaScript code back to your page tab.

Comment: when testing your `$session` variable - try changing the test to be like this : `if (!$session)`...

Comment: Solved it - found the solution:
The Solution
go to your App Setting > Facebook Integration > Page Tabs heading, and make sure your Tab URL has a trailing slash on it.

Comment: lovely :) sorry i couldnt help more ;) happy coding!

Comment: edit your  question to include your findings to help other people!  In a few days you'll be able to post your own answer to your question - and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it - found the solution**: 
The Solution go to your App Setting > Facebook Integration > Page Tabs heading, and make sure your Tab URL has a trailing slash on it.